# Django Rest Framework - How to get request.user on views.py?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django rest framework. I need to get the user on views.py but I not able to.

```
from app.models import SmsToSend
from app.serializers import SmsToSendSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from app.permissions import IsOwner
from rest_framework import permissions


class SmsToSendList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = SmsToSend.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SmsToSendSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner, permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

How can I call request.user here?

Best Regards,

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, where are you not able to call `self.request.user`?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. I think a lot of people spend time trying to figure this out. Define request as a parameter in your view method and you will have access to it like this.

```
def pre_save(self, request, obj):
    obj.owner = request.user
```

You can get your queries like this.

```
request.REQUEST.get('<query>')
```

In a serializer method it is slightly different, you can get data like this.

```
request = self.context['request']
user = request.user
query = request.GET['<query>']
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
class SmsToSendList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #queryset = SmsToSend.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SmsToSendSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner, permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return SmsToSend.objects.filter(owner=user)  

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

Instead of the queryset I had to use get_queryset method

Comment: trying to follow your example, but `pre_save` seems be ignored....  `djangorestframework==3.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = self.request.user.id
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.